# Why full control permissions on a folder are not inherited by a crt or a pvk file created in the folder?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, certificate, ntfs

I have a network folder and two machine accounts, node1$ and node2$, both of them having full control permission on the folder.

I log in a SQL Server instance in the node1 machine and back up a SQL Server certificate on the network folder, which generates a crt and a pvk files.

Then I log in node2 machine and try to restore the certificate in another SQL Server instance. But I can't because node2$ has no permissions on the requested files .crt and .pvk.

Even more, if I check the created files, the very node$1 machine account has no explicit permissions on these files. Instead, I find an "owner rights" ACE.

So, the files don't seem to inherit the permissions that node1$ and node2$ have on the folder.

This issue doesn't occur with other kind of files.

I can solve this by manually assigning explicit permissions on the files to node2$.

But my question is: why .crt and .pvk files don't inherit the permissions as other types of file do?

Comment: Can you give some details about how you *back up a SQL Server certificate*?

Comment: I use the transact sentence "backup certifcate". And when I have a look at the advanced security properties of the files the inheritance is disabled. It seems as if inheritance is disabled by default for .crt and .pvk files. (You can enable it). This doesn't occur for other types of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-certificate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) explains it:

> When performing a backup, the files will be ACLd to the service account of the SQL Server instance. If you need to restore the certificate to a server running under a different account, you will need to adjust the permissions on the files so that they are able to be read by the new account.

As you already figured out: *inheritance is disabled* because the T-SQL command `BACKUP CERTIFICATE` explicitly removes all permissions but for the service account.